# How graph database stores its data internally?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

My question is from the view of developer (not specifically respect to User) and may be bit messy.
I want to know that how the structure of Nodes and Relationships is get stored in database logically. Like, when I say that I have bla bla information. Where? - then the answer is, in BOOK, either in form of Grid or lines on a page.
In case of RDBMS, data is stored in Grid/Tabular format. But I am unable to understand how graph is get stored in Neo4j/graph database.
I am using neo4j client 2.0.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24366078/how-neo4j-stores-data-internally/24366341#24366341.

Comment: This should be deleted as the question text is a replica of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24366078/how-neo4j-stores-data-internally, the answer below should be moved to the other question

Answer (score 7):

The O'Reilly book "Graph Databases" covers the store format of Neo4j. A full, free version is available at http://graphdatabases.com