# How Neo4j stores data internally?

Tags: data-structures, neo4j

My question is from the view of developer (not specifically respect to User) and may be bit messy.
I want to know that how the structure of Nodes and Relationships is get stored in database logically. Like, when I say that I have bla bla information. Where? - then the answer is, in BOOK, either in form of Grid or lines on a page. In case of RDBMS, data is stored in Grid/Tabular format. But I am unable to understand how graph is get stored in Neo4j/graph database.
I am using neo4j client 2.1.2.

Comment: Think reference chains and graphs: http://www.slideshare.net/thobe/an-overview-of-neo4j-internals

Answer (score 24, accepted):

http://www.slideshare.net/thobe/an-overview-of-neo4j-internals is very outdated but this gives you a good overview of Neo4j logical representation.

A node references:

- its first label (my guess is that labels are stored as a singly linked list)
- its first property (properties are organized as a singly linked list)
- its start/end relationships

Relationships are organized as doubly linked lists.
A relationship points to:

- its first property (same as nodes)
- the predecessor and successor relationship of its start node
- the predecessor and successor relationship of its end node

Because of this chaining structure, the notion of traversal (i.e. THE way of querying data) easily emerges. That's why a graph database like Neo4j excels at traversing graph-structured data.

My rough guess would be also, since Neo4j version 2.1 (and [its newly introduced dense node management](http://neo4j.com/blog/the-neo4j-2-1-0-milestone-1-release-import-and-dense-nodes/)), nodes' relationships are segregated by type. By doing so, if a node N is for example a start node for 5 relationships of type A and for 5 million rels of type B, traversing rels of type A for N remains O(n=5).

Comment: I am struggling to understand how to determine predecessor and successor relationship of its start node? A node can have many incoming edges or many outgoing edges so which one is previous and next?

Comment: One can assume the relationships are stored in insertion order (and most likely grouped by type, so that the high cardinality of one relationship type doesn't affect the lookup time of a low-cardinality type).

Comment: I am failing to see the doubly linked list structure and I googled all around I still don’t see how prev and next for start and end nodes are populated and updated? Can you please explain a bit more? It doesn’t look like an adjacency list

Comment: I'm afraid it's not documented. The only option is to read the source code, as this is Neo4j's "internal sauce".

Comment: Yeah any specific file? The navigation takes a lot of time.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, I have not contributed to that part of Neo4j and Neo4j is a big, complex piece of software. You can try asking at https://community.neo4j.com/ or https://neo4j-users.slack.com.