# Directed-graph Schema Optimized for Refactoring the Graph

Tags: database-design, schema, directed-graph

I have an application whose model is best expressed as a directed graph. A given node, whether a leaf or a branch-point, can have multiple parents and multiple children, but all "top-level" parents are children of a virtual root node. So, offhand, Neo4J or some other graph database might be appropriate for the back end. Caveat: I know little about graph databases, but then again, that is why I am asking.

Looking around, most graph schemas appear to be optimized for rapid search of big data – say, millions or billions of nodes – in a mostly static graph.

In my application, though there might be many users, each user would have their own graph consisting of (most likely) thousands, not millions, of nodes, but the most common operation would be refactoring the graph. For example, adding a subnode; removing a subnode from one of its parents; adding a new parent to a subnode, adding and deleting sibling nodes, and so on.

Of course, searching the current graph is also important, but I am concerned about the cost of refactoring. And if I don't need to be, please explain why.

My question is whether a conventional graph database would be appropriate for such an application and if some might be better optimized than others for graph refactoring. Or whether there is a treatment of methodologies for this at a more theoretical level, or perhaps even software libraries for managing such a system. I've encountered things like this for hierarchies (in which a subnode may have only a single parent) but not for directed graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from a technology agnostic point of view, you don't need to worry about refactoring because the operations should be linear.

Let's use the following graph for our analysis, where `C=Customer, O=Order, P=Product, I=Item`.

[image: Graph]

Analyzing the steps to add `O4` to the graph, we have

1. Create node `O4`
2. Create relationship `R1`
3. Update node `C2` with addition of `R1`
4. Update node `O4` with addition of `R1`
5. Create relationship `R2`
6. Update node `O4` with addition of `R2`
7. Update node `P4` with addition of `R2`
8. Create relationship `R3`
9. Update node `O4` with addition of `R3`
10. Update node `P4` with addition of `R3`

So creating a node is a single operation (creating node), and creating a relationship is a minimum of 3 steps (creating relationship, updating start/end nodes).

Based on [this link about how Neo4j stores data internally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24366341/974077), we can determine that the example above is not very costly at all. And, as you noted, the subsequent searches/traversals are cheap.

If you were to consider an emerging technology, like [Apache AGE](https://age.apache.org/), the answer is a little less obvious. That's because AGE stores node and relationship data in a table and transforms Cypher into a subquery. Therefore, you would probably need to factor in the minor costs of any indexes that exist, and if none exist, that costs grows as the nodes/relationships grow.

Comment: Perhaps good to point out that when creating an edge, native graph dbs like Neo4j, Memgraph, RedisGraph, take care of updating the start/end vertices. So.. basically you just add the edges.