# AWS Neptune Performance Comparing to Neo4j desktop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

The same AWS Neptune Open Cypher queries are much slower than Neo4j Cypher queries.

we have data of employees information employees having there Project , Post and Address ,Office Location. loaded this data in Neo4j Desktop. and after exporting it loaded same data into AWS Neptune.
The DB instance is db.t3.medium with 2 CPUs and 4GiB RAM. with Engine version 1.2.0.2.
In Neptune workbench we have 'opencypher': {'version': 'Neptune-9.0.20190305-1.0'}

We have 500k nodes and 1.2 million relations in our database.

The same AWS Neptune Open Cypher queries are much slower than Neo4j Cypher queries (about 7-10 times slower).We have constraints for every Entity and full text index on name of employee in Neo4j.but we can't create them on AWS Neptune as it handles them automatically.

Is there any way to reach better performance on AWS Neptune?

Query:

```
match p=(e:Employee)-[:OFFICE_LOCATION|HAS_ADDRESS|HAS_PROJECT|HAS_ROLE]-(m)
return p
```

Comment: Hello - I just spotted this question when someone else mentioned it in another post. I added an amazon-neptune tag to help others who keep an eye out for Neptune questions to find this post. The t3.medium is a very small instance type and also on that instance statistics computation (used by the query planner) is disabled. Have you by any chance tried a larger instance type? Also, are you able to try with a newer Neptune engine version? The current latest is 1.3